# How to Iterate through table and combine it's result with the value coming from SP

Tags: sql, tsqlt

I need to join two tables in following way

```
TABLE_A

Id Name 

Table_Ref
RefID --Auto increament
```

I need to insert into Table_Ref and Join each inserted id with Table_A row

as 
     Id    Name  RefId

Do i need Cursors for this 
or any Set based operation can let me INSERT a new row into Table_Ref and then return it like

```
ID    NAME   RefID
xxxx  AAA      1
yyyy  BBB      2
```

Comment: You can't join Table_Ref with Table_A because they do not have corresponding reference columns. By which column you want to join this tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can create sequences and have that value inserted into the table

```
create sequence SEQ_TEST
minvalue 1
maxvalue 1000000000
start with 1
increment by 1
order;
```

To insert into the table, use the below syntax:

```
Insert into table_a (id, name, refid) values ('xxxx','AAA',SEQ_TEST.nextval);
Insert into table_a (id, name, refid) values ('yyyy','BBB',SEQ_TEST.nextval);
```

P.S: This is the syntax in Oracle. Not sure about tsql, you might need to tweak the syntax as necessary.

Comment: I need to insert a row in Table_Ref for each row of Table_A and insert Table_A values into Table_B along with newly inserted value in Table_Ref.

Comment: Assuming that rows are already inserted in table_ref, you can try this `SELECT id,name,d from (SELECT id,name,rownum rn1 FROM table_a) tbl1, (SELECT d,rownum rn2 FROM table_ref) tbl2
WHERE rn1 = rn2`

Comment: Rows are not already inserted, i need to insert into TableRef and get that id and ibnsert it to Table_B along with data from Tabale_A. It's a kind and merge between Table_A and Table_B. Table_B has got one additional column RefId, that will come from TableRef